# Script from foreign site cannot be handled inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I have got this certain script from a site. I put it on a div. I want to do something like this. http://www.upesspe.org/ But I can't tackle with the script in any way.

http://oil-price.net/dashboard.php?lang=en

Javascript

```
< script > $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#first').click(function () {
        $('#wti').slideDown(500);
    });

    $('.script').mouseLeave(function() {
        $('#wti').slideUp(500);
    });
}); < /script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="script">
<div id="first" class="header_06">WTI Crude Oil</div>
<div id="wti">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.oil-price.net/TABLE2/gen.php?lang=en">

    </script>
    <noscript>To get the WTI <a href="http://www.oil-price.net/dashboard.php?lang=en#TABLE2">oil price</a>, please enable Javascript.</noscript>
</div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rockyddev/9csnk/5/

PS - I updated

Comment: Describe what have you tried.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: No. No errors on my editor(Notepad ++) But it's not functioning

Comment: Does toggle() take two functions like that? I don't see that signature in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You also have several JS syntax errors on your jsFiddle. Such as funtion and etc.

Comment: @rockydgeekgod: There are a few wrong in your jsFiddle (which you can easily see by opening your browser's console). Don't include `<script>` tags in jsFiddle's JavaScript panel. Second, you haven't included the jQuery source. Thirdly, you spelled `function` wrong. You also added the external resource incorrectly - just input the URL of the script, excluding `<script>` tags.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match the code you posted here ([which works with no issues](http://jsfiddle.net/9csnk/4/)).

Comment: @COlin: I worked on what you said. But I could not understand the external resource thing. If I put the link in the tab, how am I supposed to refer it back in the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseLeave` should be in lower case and remove the `<script>` tags in jQuery. Try with the  following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#first').click(function(){
        $('#wti').slideDown();
    });
    $('.script').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#wti').slideUp(500);
    });
});
```